# Edit jTable and save results to XML

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable

I have ReadXMLFile to get data, I save the data to ArrayList, next I print the table from this ArrayList, Cells are editable, I want to edit cell or delete row, so how should  I do to save the results to XML ? Also I want to update the table when xml file will be modified outside on notepad by example.

```
  package net.kxyz;

  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

  /**
   *
        * @author kuman
   */
  public class Table extends javax.swing.JPanel {

 ReadXMLFile readXMLFile = new ReadXMLFile();
/**
 * Creates new form Table
 */
private boolean DEBUG = false;

 public Table() {

      super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
       System.out.println("SIEMANKO TABLE");
      readXMLFile.Read();
      ArrayList<Book> list = readXMLFile.getBook();

      list.add(new Book("3", "TYT", "AYUT", "231423"));
      list.get(0);
      JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(list));
      table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
       table.isCellEditable(0, 0);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
      add(scrollPane);
 }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
// End of variables declaration
  }


  class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
      private String[] columnNames = { "ID", "Title", "Author",
                "Year", "State" };
      ArrayList<Book> list = null;

      MyTableModel(ArrayList<Book> list) {
           this.list = list;
      }

      public int getColumnCount() {
           return columnNames.length;
      }

      public int getRowCount() {
           return list.size();
      }

      public String getColumnName(int col) {
           return columnNames[col];
      }

      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

           Book object = list.get(row);

           switch (col) {
           case 0:
                return object.id;
           case 1:
                return object.title;
           case 2:
                return object.author;
           case 3:
                return object.year;
           case 4:
                return object.state;
           default:
                return "unknown";
           }
      }

@Override
      public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
           return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
      }

       boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
            false, false, true, false, true,
    };

@Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex];
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){



           switch (col) {
           case 0:
               // id not editable  list.get(row).setId((int)value);
           case 1:
                list.get(row).setTitle((String)value);
               break;
           case 2:
               list.get(row).setAuthor((String)value);
               break;
           case 3:
               list.get(row).setYear((String)value);
               break;
           case 4:
                list.get(row).setState(Boolean.valueOf((String)value));
               break;

           }
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}

 }
```

ReadXMLFile.class

```
   package net.kxyz;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
   import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
   import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
   import org.w3c.dom.Document;
   import org.w3c.dom.Element;
   import org.w3c.dom.Node;
   import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
   import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

   /**
    *
    * @author kuman
    */
   public class ReadXMLFile {

    File fXmlFile = new File("/baza.xml");

    public ArrayList<Book> getBook() {
    return book;
    }
    ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>() ;
public void Read() {
    try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("book");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    System.out.println("\nReading node :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            Book tempBook = new Book();
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                tempBook.setId(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                tempBook.setTitle(eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
                tempBook.setAuthor(eElement.getElementsByTagName("author").item(0).getTextContent());
                tempBook.setYear(eElement.getElementsByTagName("year").item(0).getTextContent());
                tempBook.setState(Boolean.valueOf(eElement.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0).getTextContent()));
                System.out.println("TEMP : " + temp);
                System.out.println("id : " + tempBook.getId());
                System.out.println("title : " + tempBook.getTitle());
                System.out.println("author : " + tempBook.getAuthor());
                System.out.println("year : " + tempBook.getYear());
                System.out.println("state : " + tempBook.isState());

                book.add(temp, tempBook);

    }
}

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   }
```

Book.class

```
   package net.kxyz;

   /**
    *
    * @author kuman
    */
   public class Book {
String id;
String title;
String author;
String year;
Boolean state;

public Book() {};
public Book(String id, String title, String author, String year) {
    this.id = id ;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
    this.state = true;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public Boolean isState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(Boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}



   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> how should I do to save the results to XML ?

As far as I can see you don't have setValueAt() method implemented in your TableModel. Where your changes are saved?

In fact after editing you should go through the MyTableModel, get the List? and store it as xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a JTableListener as follows:

table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

```
  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
     // your code goes here;
  }
});
```

When, change to a table is detected you need to convert the fields of the table back into an XML.
Also, you can implement a WatchService to watch the XML file, when any change is detected to the file you can reload the table by calling ReadFromXML